# Why is the Parallax scrolling not working? (Next.js Image + Tailwind)

Tags: css, next.js, tailwind-css, parallax

What did I miss to make parallax scrolling working?

```html
<div className="h-screen">
  <div className="relative h-full w-full bg-cover bg-fixed bg-center bg-no-repeat">
    <Image src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1454496522488-7a8e488e8606?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1955&q=80'" objectFit="cover" alt="test" layout="fill" priority={true} />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think instead of `Image` component you should apply `backGroundImage` style to the `div` where you used `bg-fixed` class.

> Parallax scrolling is a web design technique in which the website
> background moves at a slower pace than the foreground.

If you visit [tailwindcss](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-attachment):

> Utilities for controlling how a background image behaves when
> scrolling.

```
 <div
        className="relative h-full w-full bg-cover  bg-center bg-fixed bg-no-repeat"
        style={{
          backgroundImage: `url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1454496522488-7a8e488e8606?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1955&q=80%27)`,
        }}
      ></div>
```

I created a component to test it out:

```
const Test = () => {
  return (
    <div className="h-screen">
      <div className="p-5 text-2xl bg-purple-300 bg-opacity-50 rounded-xl">
        Welcome to my site!
      </div>
      <div className="p-5 text-2xl bg-purple-300 bg-opacity-50 rounded-xl">
        Welcome to my site!
      </div>
      <div className="p-5 text-2xl bg-purple-300 bg-opacity-50 rounded-xl">
        Welcome to my site!
      </div>
      <div className="p-5 text-2xl bg-purple-300 bg-opacity-50 rounded-xl">
        Welcome to my site!
      </div>
      <div
        className="relative h-full w-full bg-cover  bg-center bg-fixed bg-no-repeat"
        style={{
          backgroundImage: `url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1454496522488-7a8e488e8606?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1955&q=80%27)`,
        }}
      ></div>
      <div className="p-5 text-2xl bg-purple-300 bg-opacity-50 rounded-xl">
        Welcome to my site!
      </div>
      <div className="p-5 text-2xl bg-purple-300 bg-opacity-50 rounded-xl">
        Welcome to my site!
      </div>
      <div className="p-5 text-2xl bg-purple-300 bg-opacity-50 rounded-xl">
        Welcome to my site!
      </div>
      <div className="p-5 text-2xl bg-purple-300 bg-opacity-50 rounded-xl">
        Welcome to my site!
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Test;
```

Comment: I believe this should work well, I need to be able to set the URL path dynamically as the images are set via a CMS. I forgot I could inline the style.

Comment: While this work, it won't let me take advantage of the features that the Next/Image component gives.

Comment: @octavemirbeau I do not think that you can create parallax effect with img tag. that is why I added  quotes. therei s this library `https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-parallax` but i am not sure if optimazation willl optimize those